# Pandas 0.15.2 MultiIndex vs. 0.14.1 (datetime.date vs. pandas.tslib.Timestamp)

Tags: python, pandas

When upgrading from Pandas 0.14.1 to 0.15.2, I've experienced a break in my code which I've traced it down to a MultiIndex assignment now returning a pandas.tslib.Timestamp, whereas before it was a datetime.date.

Has anyone else experienced something similar?  Is this a desired feature, or a bug in 0.15.2?  Any recommended fixes?

```
i = [dt.date(2015,1,1), dt.date(2015,1,2), dt.date(2015,1,3)]
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a', 'b'], i])

>>> idx
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'a', u'b'], [2015-01-01 00:00:00, 2015-01-02 00:00:00, 2015-01-03 00:00:00]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]])

>>> type(idx[0][1])
pandas.tslib.Timestamp

>>> idx.levels[1]
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2012-11-23, ..., 2015-03-06]
Length: 834, Freq: None, Timezone: None

>>> type(idx.levels[1][0])
Out[29]: pandas.tslib.Timestamp
```

I get the following error when running this statement:

```
df2.merge(df, left_on=['identifier', 'date'],
                        right_index=True,
                        how='left',
                        suffixes=['', '_dup'])

  File "/Users/user4589964/anaconda/envs/madrone_dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3919, in merge
    suffixes=suffixes, copy=copy)
  File "/Users/user4589964/anaconda/envs/madrone_dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 39, in merge
    return op.get_result()
  File "/Users/user4589964/anaconda/envs/madrone_dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 187, in get_result
    join_index, left_indexer, right_indexer = self._get_join_info()
  File "/Users/user4589964/anaconda/envs/madrone_dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 264, in _get_join_info
    sort=self.sort)
  File "/Users/user4589964/anaconda/envs/madrone_dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 582, in _left_join_on_index
    _get_multiindex_indexer(join_keys, right_ax, sort=sort)
  File "/Users/user4589964/anaconda/envs/madrone_dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 542, in _get_multiindex_indexer
    llab, rlab, count = _factorize_keys(level, key, sort=False)
  File "/Users/user4589964/anaconda/envs/madrone_dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 622, in _factorize_keys
    llab = rizer.factorize(lk)
TypeError: Argument 'values' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got Index)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in index construction, see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7888)

Here's an example of how to use an actual `datetime.date` object

```
In [8]: pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([Index([datetime.date(2013,1,1)]),['a']])
Out[8]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[[2013-01-01], [u'a']],
           labels=[[0], [0]])
```

Keep in mind that `datetime.date` are really 2nd class citizens and will consequently be represented as `object` dtypes, thus not very efficiently. You generally should simply use `Timestamps`.